Flutter app iOS red screen error Stack Overflow
I can run my app on android simulator and phisical device too well, I can generate apk as well but when I try to run my app on iOS I get error after Catcher2 in my main.dart
void main() async {
  final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  // Init Hive before get storage
  await Hive.initFlutter();
  Hive.registerAdapter(RefreshTokenAdapter());
  RefreshToken storage = RefreshToken();
  await storage.openBox();
  // Initialize App
  await Firebase.initializeApp(
    // name: "dovevivo",
    // options: DefaultFirebaseOptions.currentPlatform,
  );
  // Setting FCM Token on storage
  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getToken().then((value) async {
    String? fcmToken = value;
    storage.setFcmToken(fcmToken ?? ""); 
    print('FCMToken:' + fcmToken!);
  });
  // Enable Android/iOS Push Notification config with redirects
  await PushNotificationConfig(App.navigatorKey).setupInteractedMessage();
  // Check that Localization is enabled
  await EasyLocalization.ensureInitialized();
  // Permissions requests
  await Permission.camera.request();
  await Permission.photos.request();
  await Permission.notification.isDenied.then((value) async {
    if (value) {
      await Permission.notification.request();
    }
  });
  await SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations(
    [DeviceOrientation.portraitUp, DeviceOrientation.portraitDown],
  );
  if (kDebugMode && Platform.isAndroid) {
    await AndroidInAppWebViewController.setWebContentsDebuggingEnabled(true);
  }

  // Bloc.observer = AppBlocObserver();
  final sentryHandler = await makeSentryHandler();
  final customParameters = await makeCustomParameters();

  final catcherDebugOptions = Catcher2Options(
    SilentReportMode(),
    [ConsoleHandler()],
    customParameters: customParameters,
  );

  final catcherReleaseOptions = Catcher2Options(
    SilentReportMode(),
    [sentryHandler],
    customParameters: customParameters,
  );

  Catcher2(
    rootWidget: const App(),
    debugConfig: catcherDebugOptions,
    releaseConfig: catcherReleaseOptions,
    navigatorKey: App.navigatorKey,
    ensureInitialized: true,
  );
}

Future<CustomSentryHandler> makeSentryHandler() async {
  final packageInfo = await PackageInfo.fromPlatform();
  final version = packageInfo.version;
  final buildNumber = packageInfo.buildNumber;
  return CustomSentryHandler(
    sentry.SentryClient(
      sentry.SentryOptions(dsn: AppConfig.SENTRY_DSN),
    ),
    customRelease: '$version+$buildNumber',
  );
}

Future<Map<String, dynamic>> makeCustomParameters() async {
  const deviceInfo = DeviceInfoChecker();
  final systemDescription = await deviceInfo.getSystemDescription();

  return {'system': systemDescription};
}

my app.dart:
bool? isLoggedIn;

class App extends StatelessWidget {
  static final navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  static final bottomBarKey = GlobalKey<HomeBottomBarState>();
  static final mainNavigationDelegate =
      MainRouterDelegate(MainNavigationStack([const MainNavigation.splash()]));
  static final mainNavigationParser = MainRouterInformationParser();

  static Locale? get currentLocale => App.navigatorKey.currentContext?.locale;

  final DependencyFactory dependencyFactory;

  const App({
    Key? key,
    this.dependencyFactory = const DependencyFactoryImpl(),
  }) : super(key: key);


  void authListener(BuildContext context, AuthLoginInAppState state) async {
    await state.maybeWhen(
      authError: (_) => showDialog(
        context: App.navigatorKey.currentContext!,
        builder: (context) => AlertDialog(
          content: Text(tr('session_expired')),
          actions: [
            TextButton(
              onPressed: Navigator.of(context).pop,
              child: Text(tr('ok')),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      orElse: () {},
    );
    mainNavigationDelegate.stack.items = [const MainNavigation.login()];
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return DependencyProvider(
      dependencyFactory: const DependencyFactoryImpl(),
      child: Builder(
        builder: (context) => LocalizationWrapper(
          child: Builder(
            builder: (context) => MultiBlocListener(
              listeners: [
                BlocListener<AuthLoginInAppBloc, AuthLoginInAppState>(
                  listenWhen: (previousState, currentState) =>
                      previousState.maybeWhen(
                          loggedIn: (_) => currentState.maybeWhen(
                                loggedOut: () => true,
                                authError: (_) => true,
                                orElse: () => false,
                              ),
                          orElse: () => false),
                  listener: authListener,
                ),
                BlocListener<UserDataBloc, UserDataState>(
                  listenWhen: (previous, current) => current.maybeWhen(
                    fetchState: (state) => state.maybeWhen(
                      loaded: (_) => true,
                      orElse: () => false,
                    ),
                    orElse: () => false,
                  ),
                  listener: (context, state) => state.maybeWhen(
                    fetchState: (state) => state.maybeWhen(
                      loaded: (model) =>
                          context.setLocale(model.language.toLocale),
                      orElse: () {},
                    ),
                    orElse: () {},
                  ),
                )
              ],
              child: DvNavigatorObservers(
                child: FlowControllersProvider(
                  child: MaterialApp.router(
                    routerDelegate: mainNavigationDelegate,
                    routeInformationParser: mainNavigationParser,
                    localizationsDelegates: context.localizationDelegates,
                    supportedLocales: context.supportedLocales,
                    locale: context.locale,
                    themeMode: ThemeMode.light,
                    theme: AppTheme.light,
                    darkTheme: AppTheme.dark,
                    builder: (context, child) {
                      final existingFactor =
                          MediaQuery.of(context).textScaleFactor;
                      LayoutUtils.updateScaleFactor(
                        context,
                        existingFactor: existingFactor,
                      );
                      return MediaQuery(
                        data: MediaQuery.of(context).copyWith(
                          textScaleFactor: LayoutUtils.textScaleFactor,
                        ),
                        child: child!,
                      );
                    },
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}


the error:
enter image description here

Stack Overflow Logs:
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Localization initialized<…>
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.175690 | Catcher 2 | WARNING] Screenshots path is empty. Screenshots won't work.
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.195715 | Catcher 2 | FINE] Catcher 2 configured successfully.
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Start<…>
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init state<…>
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Build<…>
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init Localization Delegate<…>
flutter: \^[[90m[ Easy Localization] [DEBUG] Init provider<…>
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.369578 | Catcher 2 | INFO] Setup localization lazily!
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.390248 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ============================== CATCHER 2 LOG ==============================
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.390513 | Catcher 2 | INFO] Crash occurred on 2024-09-09 14:25:58.389253
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.390624 | Catcher 2 | INFO]
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.390879 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ------- DEVICE INFO -------
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.391463 | Catcher 2 | INFO]
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.391669 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ------- APP INFO -------
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392195 | Catcher 2 | INFO] environment: debug
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392384 | Catcher 2 | INFO] version: 3.5.47
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392535 | Catcher 2 | INFO] appName: Joivy Staging
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392666 | Catcher 2 | INFO] buildNumber: 20584
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392826 | Catcher 2 | INFO] packageName: com.dovevivo.app.staging
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.392970 | Catcher 2 | INFO]
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.393095 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ---------- ERROR ----------
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.393221 | Catcher 2 | INFO] Stack Overflow
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.393348 | Catcher 2 | INFO]
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.393584 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ------- STACK TRACE -------
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394004 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #0      _AssertionError._evaluateAssertion (dart:core-patch/errors_patch.dart:56:3)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394103 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #1      new DiagnosticsNode (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394217 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #2      new DiagnosticableNode (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394352 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3      Diagnosticable.toDiagnosticsNode (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3050:12)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394469 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #4      Diagnosticable.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3034:20)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394598 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #5      Diagnosticable.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3036:6)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394713 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #6      DiagnosticsProperty.valueToString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2641:60)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394849 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #7      DiagnosticsProperty.toDescription (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:2658:21)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.394968 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #8      TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1195:31)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395093 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #9      TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1125:14)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395260 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #10     TextTreeRenderer._debugRender (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1311:39)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395384 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #11     TextTreeRenderer.render (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1125:14)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395515 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #12     DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1782:9)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395625 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #13     DiagnosticsNode.toStringDeep (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1789:6)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395750 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #14     DiagnosticsNode.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1700:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395873 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #15     DiagnosticsNode.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:1712:6)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.395970 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #16     Diagnosticable.toString.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3034:78)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396067 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #17     Diagnosticable.toString (package:flutter/src/foundation/diagnostics.dart:3036:6)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396249 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #18     _StringBase._interpolate (dart:core-patch/string_patch.dart:866:19)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396352 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #19     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5510:44)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396446 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #20     StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5643:11)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396669 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #21     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396804 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #22     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.396915 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #23     StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397007 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #24     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397108 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #25     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397218 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #26     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397323 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #27     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397408 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #28     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397534 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #29     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397643 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #30     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397737 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #31     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397824 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #32     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.397927 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #33     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398020 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #34     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398109 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #35     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398198 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #36     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398280 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #37     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398352 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #38     Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398433 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #39     ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398505 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #40     Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398580 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #41     ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398658 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #42     ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398725 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #43     Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398799 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ...
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398891 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ...
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.398965 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3787   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399082 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3788   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399211 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3789   StatefulElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5643:11)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399345 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3790   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399459 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3791   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399571 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3792   StatefulElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5634:11)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399673 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3793   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399788 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3794   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.399936 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3795   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400073 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3796   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400212 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3797   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400340 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3798   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400455 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3799   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400568 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3800   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400686 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3801   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400828 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3802   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.400957 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3803   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401118 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3804   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401221 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3805   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401325 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3806   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401422 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3807   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401536 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3808   _RawViewElement._updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:291:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401619 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3809   _RawViewElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/view.dart:314:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401745 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3810   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.401871 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3811   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402029 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3812   ComponentElement.performRebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5505:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402147 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3813   Element.rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5196:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402248 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3814   ComponentElement._firstBuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5462:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402335 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3815   ComponentElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:5456:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402409 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3816   Element.inflateWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:4335:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402499 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3817   Element.updateChild (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:3846:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402584 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3818   RootElement._rebuild (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1354:16)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402685 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3819   RootElement.mount (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1323:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402772 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3820   RootWidget.attach.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1276:18)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402906 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3821   BuildOwner.buildScope (package:flutter/src/widgets/framework.dart:2844:19)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.402979 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3822   RootWidget.attach (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1275:13)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403054 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3823   WidgetsBinding.attachToBuildOwner (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1088:27)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403123 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3824   WidgetsBinding.attachRootWidget (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1070:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403197 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3825   WidgetsBinding.scheduleAttachRootWidget.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/binding.dart:1056:7)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403276 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3826   Timer._createTimer.<anonymous closure> (dart:async-patch/timer_patch.dart:18:15)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403357 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3827   _Timer._runTimers (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:398:19)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403457 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3828   _Timer._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/timer_impl.dart:429:5)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403539 | Catcher 2 | INFO] #3829   _RawReceivePort._handleMessage (dart:isolate-patch/isolate_patch.dart:184:12)
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403635 | Catcher 2 | INFO]
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.403831 | Catcher 2 | INFO] ======================================================================
flutter: [2024-09-09 14:25:58.406042 | Catcher 2 | INFO] Report result: true

Sometimes when I reload the app it works fine, specially when I run the app with flutter dev tools on browser opened. Maybe it's something about MaterialApp ? I'm stuck on this
I update Catcher with Catcher2 and in android it works fine. This is my flutter doctor:
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.19.0, on macOS 14.6.1 23G93 darwin-arm64, locale en-IT)
    • Flutter version 3.19.0 on channel stable at /Users/alberto.callegari/flutter
    • Upstream repository https://github.com/flutter/flutter.git
    • Framework revision bae5e49bc2 (7 months ago), 2024-02-13 17:46:18 -0800
    • Engine revision 04817c99c9
    • Dart version 3.3.0
    • DevTools version 2.31.1

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
    • Android SDK at /Users/alberto.callegari/Library/Android/sdk
    • Platform android-34, build-tools 34.0.0
    • ANDROID_HOME = /Users/alberto.callegari/Library/Android/sdk
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jbr/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.4)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Build 15F31d
    • CocoaPods version 1.15.2

[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
    • Chrome at /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome

[✓] Android Studio (version 2024.1)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/9212-flutter
    • Dart plugin can be installed from:
       https://plugins.jetbrains.com/plugin/6351-dart
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.11+0-17.0.11b1207.24-11852314)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.92.2)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 3.96.0


[✓] Network resources
    • All expected network resources are available.

• No issues found!


And if you don't use Catcher, and rely only on Sentry for error reporting? It may be a useful test anyway: remove Catcher and see if the error still happens

@il_boga I tried but I still get the error and I cannot facing the reason, I update my question with my app.dart

But now the error is still stack overflow, or is the failed assertion? The link still points to a stack overflow screenshot, but the attached image is another...
The issue seems quite complicated, though, and both the error are pretty generic, especially if it's still the overflow one. On the other hand, trying to understand which assertion fails might be helpful to understand what's wrong.
The stacktrace you posted is complete, or there's something else?

@il_boga thans a lot for the answer, about the errors sometimes I had the one on the link and sometimes the other one. If I open dev tools on browser the app starts running and this is really weird at my point. Now I just update my question with the entire stacktrace

Ugh, this looks awful. I'd start by upgrading both Dart and Flutter, just to be sure you're not running into some obscure but already fixed bug.
By searching the error code related to the assertion, I found that other people ran into something that might be similar to your case: I know that is not much, but it's something.
SO question: Flutter 'owner!._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this': is not true. #87
Another SO question: owner._debugCurrentBuildTarget == this , is not true
Github issue: https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/105022
Your app seems to be complex enough to make it impossible for us debug the whole problem, I don't think there's much more that I can do.

Thanks for your reply! I don't know if it can help you but I tried to add a breakpoint in my app.dart file in LocalizationWrapper builder and I found that it stops twice the first time I get the error while the second time the app works fine

That could be a starting point: you just need to check where in the code you build twice that LocalizationWrapper, and try to understand if you can invoke it only once.

thanks a lot bro for the support.. is it possible that the error is cause I have to update my flutter_bloc package?

I don't think so, at least not with a popular package like bloc: a breaking change like that would have been mentioned somewhere in their changelog. This looks like something a async method put where it should not be, a missing WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized() or too many widgets instantiated at the same time. Something trivial and well hidden, but trivial nonetheless.
